How powerful is a grammar where each rule accepts a numerical parameter?
This question came out of an attempt to figure out the easiest way to express a formal grammar accepting context-sensitive languages like Python's indentation-sensitive syntax. It seems like the most natural way would be a grammar where rules can accept numerical parameters, like:
$\begin{align*}
I &::= S(0) \\
S(n) &::= a^nE(n) \\
E(n) &::= bT(n)\mid bS(n)\mid bD(n)\mid b \\
T(n) &::= S(n+1) \\
D(n + 1) &::= S(n) \\
D(0) &::= S(0)
\end{align*}$
So rules like $T$ increase the indentation and rules like $D$ decrease it, while rules like $S$ output some number of prefix characters like spaces before the actual expression $E$ (in this example you can think of terminals $a$ as a space and $b$ as an expression).
I don't claim this is a novel form of grammar as several people I know independently came up with the same idea. However, I'm interested in whether this type of grammar (or something similar) has a well-known name, and also how powerful it is relative to other classes in the Chomsky hierarchy like context-free grammars, context-sensitive grammars, and Turing machines.

For me the equation doesn't show up right -- linebreaks don't show up in the typeset output.  I don't know whether that is just me.  You might want to use \begin{align*}..\end{align*}.

This is a special case of indexed grammars with just one index symbol (where a stack of these symbols represents your $n$ in unary).

Indexed grammars seem like a good lead. They might even be more powerful than the grammars depicted here, but I will experiment this weekend.

In his 1986 paper "Context-free grammars with storage" Joost Engelfriet proposes a formalism that covers various types of grammars, both for strings and trees, as well as some transducers. https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.0683
This includes context-free grammars where the nonterminals carry a pushdown stack, and in the productions this pushdown may be popped or pushed. Indexed grammars are then restricted to stacks that behave as a counter. They can only contain copies of a single symbol. Engelfriet observes (page 19, after Def. 3.4):

The CF(Counter) grammar is a special type of indexed grammar: the
1-block-indexed grammar (see [W. J. Erni; On the time and tape
complexity of hyper(1)-AFL’s, Proc. 4-th ICALP, Lecture Notes in
Computer Science 52, Springer-Verlag, 1977, pp. 230–243]).

Sorry, but I did not verify the details here. Please check the reference: https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-08342-1_18. Whereas I am familiar with indexed grammars, this particular restriction is new to me.
